# React Native Firebase Notifications aren't always shown

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase, firebase-notifications

We have a React-Native app on iOS and Android. We use RN 0.61.5 and react-native-firebase 5.5.6.

We use react-native-firebase/notifications to add local notifications on the device. When we test this these notifications are planned correct but we get the feedback from some of our users that they don’t receive the notifications. I have added our notifications.ts file and our NotificationListener.tsx file below.

Does someone have an idea, possible reason of tips for debug/improve/fix our notifications?

**Code**

notifications.ts:

```
// Firebase Notifications
// ---
// Custom implementation on top of the Firebase Notifications library.
// This class is responsable for creating, scheduling and re-scheduling notifications.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /

import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import { Notification } from "react-native-firebase/notifications";
import { Recycle } from "@shd-types/fp-recycle-api";
import { isEmpty } from "ramda";

import { Store } from "../../store";
import { IS_ANDROID, IS_IOS } from "../../utils/device-info";
import i18n, { manualTranslate } from "../../utils/i18n";

import { NotificationsState } from "../../features/notifications/store/notifications.types";
import { CollectionRoundsState } from "../../features/collection-rounds/store/collectionRounds.types";
import { ProfileState } from "../../features/profile/store/profile.types";

const MAX_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS = 64;

class FirebaseNotifications {

    private permissionsGranted: boolean = false;
    private language: string;
    private notificationState: NotificationsState;
    private collectionRoundsState: CollectionRoundsState;
    private profileState: ProfileState;

    constructor() {
        // Ask for permission to send notifications
        this.init();

        const store: any = Store.getState();
        this.language = store.global.language;
        this.notificationState = store.notifications;
        this.collectionRoundsState = store.collectionRounds;
        this.profileState = store.profile;

        // Create an Android Notification Channel
        // More info on this here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android-channels
        this.initChannels();
    }

    async init(): Promise<void> {
        const store: any = Store.getState();
        this.language = store.global.language;
        this.notificationState = store.notifications;
        this.collectionRoundsState = store.collectionRounds;
        this.profileState = store.profile;

        if (this.permissionsGranted) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }

        const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();

        if (!enabled) {
            try {
                await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
                this.permissionsGranted = true;
            } catch (error) {
                // User has rejected permissions
                this.permissionsGranted = false;
                return Promise.reject();
            }
        } else {
            this.permissionsGranted = true;
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    async initChannels() {
        // Create the channel groups
        await firebase.notifications().android.createChannelGroups([
            // Main channel group
            new firebase.notifications.Android.ChannelGroup("general", "General"),

            // Channel group for each address
            new firebase.notifications.Android.ChannelGroup("collections-home", "Home"),
        ]);

        // Build a channel
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel("collection-rounds-channel", "Collection Rounds", firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
            .setDescription("Notifications for Collection Rounds")
            .setGroup("collections-home");

        // Create the channel
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
    }

    // Collection Build Methods
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /
    setAndroidNotificationProps(notification: Notification, channelId?: string, group?: string) {
        // https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification
        notification
            .android.setLocalOnly(true)
            .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.Max)

            // Notification Style
            .android.setColor("green") // Sets the accent color to use
            .android.setVibrate([500, 500]) // Set notification vibration pattern.
            .android.setLights(0xFF97E92A, 500, 500) // Set notification light to green.
            .android.setSmallIcon("ic_launcher");


        if (channelId) {
            notification
                .android.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
        if (group) {
            notification
                .android.setGroup(group)
                .android.setGroupAlertBehaviour(firebase.notifications.Android.GroupAlert.All);
        }
    }

    setIOSNotificationProps(notification: Notification, category?: string) {
        // https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification
        notification
            .ios.setHasAction(false); // IOS 9 only.

        if (category) {
            notification
                .ios.setCategory(category);
        }
    }

    buildOpenAppNotification(fireDate: number): Notification {
        const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(`general-open-app-reminder-${fireDate}`)
            .setTitle(i18n._("notifications.appRefresh.title"))
            .setBody(i18n._("notifications.appRefresh.body"))
            .setSound("default")
            .setData({
                schedule: {
                    fireDate,
                },
            });

        if (IS_ANDROID) {
            this.setAndroidNotificationProps(notification, "general");
        }

        if (IS_IOS) {
            this.setIOSNotificationProps(notification, "general");
            notification
                .ios.setBadge(1);
        }

        return notification;
    }

    buildCollectionNotification(collection: Recycle.Collection.CollectionRound, fireDate?: number, sameDay = false): Notification {
        const collectionTypeNames = collection.types.map((collectionType: Recycle.Type.Item) => manualTranslate(collectionType.name, this.language));

        const notificationTitle = sameDay
            ? `${i18n._("notifications.collectionSameDay.title")}: ${collectionTypeNames.join(", ")}`
            : `${i18n._("notifications.collectionDayBefore.title")}: ${collectionTypeNames.join(", ")}`;

        // TODO: Map this to the location, if multiple
        const notificationSubtitle = i18n._(this.profileState.address[0].alias);

        const notificationBody = sameDay
            ? i18n._("notifications.collectionSameDay.body")
            : i18n._("notifications.collectionDayBefore.body");

        const notificationBodyExtended = sameDay
            ? i18n._("notifications.collectionSameDay.bodyExtended")
            : i18n._("notifications.collectionDayBefore.bodyExtended");

        const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(`notification-collection-${collection.id}-${fireDate}`)
            .setTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSubtitle(notificationSubtitle)
            .setBody(notificationBody)
            .setData({
                ...collection,
                schedule: {
                    fireDate,
                },
            })
            .setSound("default");

        if (IS_ANDROID) {
            this.setAndroidNotificationProps(notification, "collection-rounds-channel", "collections");
            notification.android
                .setBigText(
                    notificationBodyExtended,
                    notificationTitle,
                    notificationBody
                );
        }

        if (IS_IOS) {
            this.setIOSNotificationProps(notification, "collections");
        }

        return notification;
    }

    resetNotificationBadge() {
        if (IS_IOS) {
            const notifications = firebase.notifications();
            notifications.setBadge(0);
        }
    }

    // Scheduling Methods
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /
    async rescheduleNotifications(collections?: Recycle.Collection.CollectionRound[]) {
        // Clear all scheduled notifications
        const notifications = await firebase.notifications().getScheduledNotifications();

        if (notifications) {
            notifications
                .forEach((notification: Notification) => {
                    firebase.notifications().cancelNotification(notification.notificationId);
                });
        }

        collections = collections ? collections : this.collectionRoundsState.data;

        if (!collections) {
            return;
        }

        // Check if the user has given permission to receive notifications
        try {
            await this.init();
        } catch (err) {
            return;
        }

        // Fetch the notificationsSettings
        const homeNotificationSettings = this.notificationState.settings.home;

        // TODO
        // 1. Account for the amount of notifications (e.g. the day before AND the current day)
        // 2. Account for the amount of addresses to schedule for.
        //
        // We will simulate this for now. (simplified)
        const numberOfNotificationsPerCollection = Object.values(homeNotificationSettings.time).filter((timeSetting) => timeSetting.enabled).length;
        const numberOfAddresses = 1;
        const numberOfCollectionsToSchedule = Math.floor(MAX_ALLOWED_NOTIFICATIONS / (numberOfAddresses * numberOfNotificationsPerCollection)) - 1;

        // TODO
        // 1. Account for the time when we want the notification.

        let lastNotificationTime = 0;

        let collectionTypesToNotNotify: string[] = [];

        // Filter out the collectionTypes we don't want a notification for.
        if (homeNotificationSettings) {
            collectionTypesToNotNotify = Object.values(homeNotificationSettings.categories)
                .filter((category) => !category.enabled )
                .map((category) => category.key);
        }

        // Reschedule all collections
        collections
            .filter((collection) => {
                // Filter out collections that have passed
                if (new Date(collection.date).valueOf() < new Date().valueOf()) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Filter out collections that are not wanted
                if (collectionTypesToNotNotify.length) {
                    const allow = [];
                    const localCollectionTypes = collection.types.map((type) => type.id);

                    for (const collectionType of localCollectionTypes) {
                        allow.push(!collectionTypesToNotNotify.includes(collectionType));
                    }

                    // The collection has at least 1 item we want notifications for.
                    return allow.includes(true);
                }

                return true;
            })
            .map((collection) => {
                // Filter out the collections the user does not want.
                if (!collectionTypesToNotNotify.length) {
                    return collection;
                }

                const localCollectionTypes = collection.types.map((type) => type.id);

                return {
                    ...collection,
                    types: localCollectionTypes.filter((collectionType) => {
                        return !collectionTypesToNotNotify.includes(collectionType);
                    }),
                };
            })
            .slice(0, numberOfCollectionsToSchedule)
            .forEach((collection, index, arr) => {
                const collectionDay = new Date(collection.date);

                let collectionNotificationTime = 0;
                let collectionHour = 0;
                let collectionMinutes = 0;

                if (homeNotificationSettings.time.dayBefore.enabled) {
                    // Get the day before
                    const collectionNotificationDate = new Date(collectionDay).setDate(collectionDay.getDate() - 1);

                    // Set the notification hour
                    collectionHour = homeNotificationSettings.time.dayBefore.hours;
                    collectionMinutes = homeNotificationSettings.time.dayBefore.minutes;
                    collectionNotificationTime = new Date(collectionNotificationDate).setHours(collectionHour, collectionMinutes);

                    // Schedule the notification if it triggers in the future
                    this.scheduleCollectionNotification(collection, collectionNotificationTime);
                }

                if (homeNotificationSettings.time.dayOf.enabled) {
                    // Set the notification hour
                    collectionHour = homeNotificationSettings.time.dayOf.hours;
                    collectionMinutes = homeNotificationSettings.time.dayOf.minutes;
                    collectionNotificationTime = new Date(collectionDay).setHours(collectionHour, collectionMinutes);

                    // Schedule the notification if it triggers in the future
                    this.scheduleCollectionNotification(collection, collectionNotificationTime, true);
                }

                // Schedule the "open your app please" notification after 10 notifcations
                // And after the last one
                if ((index !== 0 && index % 10 === 0) || (index === arr.length - 1)) {
                    // Plan the reminder 1 day after the previous notification
                    const collectionDate = new Date(collectionDay).setDate(collectionDay.getDate() + 1);
                    lastNotificationTime = new Date(collectionDate).setHours(collectionHour, collectionMinutes);
                    firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(
                        this.buildOpenAppNotification(lastNotificationTime),
                        { fireDate: lastNotificationTime }
                    );
                }
            });
    }

    scheduleCollectionNotification(collection: Recycle.Collection.CollectionRound, fireDate: number, sameDay = false) {
        // Schedule the notification if it triggers in the future
        if (fireDate > new Date().valueOf() && !isEmpty(this.notificationState.settings.home.categories)) {
            firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(
                this.buildCollectionNotification(collection, fireDate, sameDay),
                { fireDate }
            );
        }
    }
}

export default new FirebaseNotifications();
```

NotificationListener.tsx:

````
import React from "react";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import { Notification, NotificationOpen } from "react-native-firebase/notifications";

interface Props {
    children: any;
}

class NotificationListener extends React.Component<Props> {

    private notificationDisplayedListener: (notification?: Notification) => void;
    private notificationListener: (notification?: Notification) => void;
    private notificationOpenedListener: (notificationOpen?: NotificationOpen) => void;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed(this.onNotificationDisplayed);
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification(this.onNotification);
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(this.onNotificationOpened);

        this.onNotificationDisplayed = this.onNotificationDisplayed.bind(this);
        this.onNotification = this.onNotification.bind(this);
        this.onNotificationOpened = this.onNotificationOpened.bind(this);
    }

    // Lifecycle Methods
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /
    // https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/receiving-notifications#App-Closed
    async componentDidMount() {
        const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        if (notificationOpen) {
            // App was opened by a notification
            this.onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen);
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.notificationDisplayedListener();
        this.notificationListener();
        this.notificationOpenedListener();
    }


    // Callback Methods
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /

    // Triggered when a particular notification has been displayed
    onNotificationDisplayed(notification: Notification) {
        // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.

        // Leave this for debugging purposes
        // console.log("Notification Displayed!:", notification);
    }

    // Triggered when a particular notification has been received, but not displayed
    onNotification(notification: Notification) {
        // Leave this for debugging purposes
        // console.log("Notification received, but not displayed!:", notification);

        // Force the notification in the OS NotificationBar
        firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
    }

    // Triggered when a particular notification has been clicked / tapped / opened whent he app is in the foreground or background.
    onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) {
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;

        // Leave this for debugging purposes
        // console.log("Notification Opened!:", notificationOpen);

        // Remove the notification once it has been openend.
        firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notificationOpen.notification.notificationId);
    }

    // Render Methods
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------- /
    render() {
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

export default NotificationListener;```
````

Comment: If only some of your users notice, that they don't receive messages, it doesn't seem an error for your implementation. If I should guess, I would say they don't allow to receive Notifications for the App as the App asked for the permission. First before you start to debug your app, make sure, they're settings in the device are fine (Notification-Permission granted). - If all fine, get there device-manufacturers and look in Google-Dev for crashes & errors which could cause the issue.

Comment: Hi! I also am facing the same issue. All my notifications in the app are scheduled and they work for 2 to 3 days then stop appearing! MANY users have reported to me that they stop working and it is getting really frustrating. Did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: Hey, we think that the source of our problem is batter saving. Some OS's put the device in battery-saving mode. We are going to try to ask the user to disable battery saving with this package. https://github.com/rasheedk/react-native-disable-battery-optimizations-android